# Обстоятельства образа действия и цели в качестве однородных членов

Tags: грамотная-речь, однородные-члены, обстоятельство

*Он делал комплименты **искренне**, а не **с целью добиться расположения**.*

Грамотно ли в качестве однородных членов использовать обстоятельства разных видов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Искренний*** – это **подлинный, правдивый**, в данном случае делать комплименты ***искренне*** – это говорить правду. А  делать это ради какой-либо цели – значит говорить неискренне.

Таким образом мы видим **контекстуальное семантическое сближение разных обстоятельств (образа действия и цели),** что позволяет считать их однородными.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, здесь в подтексте есть отсутствие цели в первой части и неискренность во второй. Поэтому предложение воспринимается нормально.